# Operation of simple FM transmitter circuit

Tags: oscillator, frequency-modulation

I found the following little FM transmitter circuit among some old papers and it works pretty well, but I have a tough time understanding how the circuit operates:

[image]

I understand the trimcap and inductor form a LC tank circuit that resonates at the required frequency. I don't understand how the transistor keeps the tank "topped up". Can anyone explain the circuit's operation in detail ?

Comment: C2 provides positive feedback from collector (output) to emitter (amplifier input)

Comment: That's an oscillator and not an FM transmitter.

Comment: There is a capacitive loop: C4, C2, Ceb, and C3.